# User isn't created to mongodb when using webhooks

Tags: next.js

`I am building a website with nextjs latest version(14) app router.in that website for login I am using clerkId,webhooks.What I want in my website is that when a user signUp, his info will saved to mongoDb database.The problem is that user can register through clerkId but his info isn't saved to the mongodb database. Here are my code:

/api/webhook/route.ts

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import { Webhook } from "svix";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { WebhookEvent } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { createUser, deleteUser, updateUser } from "@/lib/actions/user.action";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // You can find this in the Clerk Dashboard -> Webhooks -> choose the webhook
  const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.NEXT_CLERK_WEBHOOK_SECRET;
  console.log(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

  if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local"
    );
  }

  // Get the headers
  const headerPayload = headers();
  const svix_id = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
  const svix_timestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
  const svix_signature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");

  // If there are no headers, error out
  if (!svix_id || !svix_timestamp || !svix_signature) {
    return new Response("Error occured -- no svix headers", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the body
  const payload = await req.json();
  const body = JSON.stringify(payload);

  // Create a new SVIX instance with your secret.
  const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

  let evt: WebhookEvent;

  // Verify the payload with the headers
  try {
    evt = wh.verify(body, {
      "svix-id": svix_id,
      "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
      "svix-signature": svix_signature,
    }) as WebhookEvent;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error verifying webhook:", err);
    return new Response("Error occured", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  const eventType = evt.type;

  console.log({ eventType });

  if (eventType === "user.created") {
    const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
      evt.data;
    console.log("Event data:", {
      id,
      email_addresses,
      image_url,
      username,
      first_name,
      last_name,
    });

    `// Create a new user in your database
    const mongoUser = await createUser({
      clerkId: id,
      name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
      username: username!,
      email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
      picture: image_url,
    });
    console.log(mongoUser);

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
  }

  if (eventType === "user.updated") {
    const { id, email_addresses, image_url, username, first_name, last_name } =
      evt.data;

    // Create a new user in your database
    const mongoUser = await updateUser({
      clerkId: id,
      updateData: {
        name: `${first_name}${last_name ? ` ${last_name}` : ""}`,
        username: username!,
        email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
        picture: image_url,
      },
      path: `/profile/${id}`,
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: mongoUser });
  }

  if (eventType === "user.deleted") {
    const { id } = evt.data;

    const deletedUser = await deleteUser({
      clerkId: id!,
    });

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK", user: deletedUser });
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "OK" });
}

//user.action.ts
"use server";

import User from "@/database/user.model";
import { connectToDatabase } from "../mongoose";
import {
  CreateUserParams,
  DeleteUserParams,
  UpdateUserParams,
} from "./shared.types";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import Question from "@/database/question.model";

export async function getUserById(params: any) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();

    const { userId } = params;
    const user = await User.findOne({ clerkId: userId });
    return user;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function createUser(userData: CreateUserParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();

    const newUser = await User.create(userData);
    console.log("User created:", newUser);
    return newUser;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating user:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function updateUser(params: UpdateUserParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();

    const { clerkId, updateData, path } = params;

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({ clerkId }, updateData, {
      new: true,
    });

    revalidatePath(path);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function deleteUser(params: DeleteUserParams) {
  try {
    connectToDatabase();
    const { clerkId } = params;

    const user = await User.findOneAndDelete({ clerkId });
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error("User not found");
    }

    
    await Question.deleteMany({ author: user._id });

    

    const deletedUser = await User.findByIdAndDelete(user._id);
    return deletedUser;
  } catch (error) {}
}
`


in vercel logs it's saying status code 401.
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to debug this is by using a tool like ngrok that lets you call your webhook. Run ngrok and paste the url feom ngrok into your clerk dashboard/ webhooks.